# mapStateToProps does not set the data in component props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm just getting started with React. I successfully used axios to get data from http and use an action to push the data. I can output the data at `mapStateToProps` but it does not set the data as a `prop` in the class. Here's my code with comments about the availability of the data.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCountries } from '../../actions/actions';
import _ from 'lodash';

class TheClass extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        this.props.fetchCountries();
        console.log('Fetching', this.props.countries);      // !! UNDEFINED !!
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state)
{
    console.log('Countries:', state.countries)                // -> I get the data
    return { countries: state.countries }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchCountries })(TheClass);
```

**actions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_COUNTRIES = `fetch_countries`;
const COUNTRIES_URL = `http://api.stagingapp.io/location/v1/public/country`;

export function fetchCountries()
{
    const request = axios.get(COUNTRIES_URL);
    console.log(request);                                // -> I get the data
    return {
        type: FETCH_COUNTRIES,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

Comment: that could be because intiially, reducer is not returning anything and then once Action is triggered the Value is populated, but now it wont be picked up since componentDidmount is run only once. Add `console.log(this.props.countries)` in the render and you can be sure

Comment: Actions is not the right place to make a network call. Use a middleware like thunk or redux-saga (preferably). All your network calls should go in the middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**fetchCountries** is an asynchronous operation so you can't expect the result just after calling **fetchCountries** as you are trying to do in **componentDidMount**.

If you are getting the result in connect function, then you will get the result in render function after successful network call.

Put your console here:

```
render() {
    console.log('Fetching', this.props.countries);   
}
```

Comment: Oh, that explains why. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd imagine that `state.countries` gets populated by whatever response you get from your **asynchronous** HTTP request in `fetchCountries()`.

Only once this request resolves, should you get the country data. When you call `fetchCountries()` and immediately afterwards try to print out the value of `countries`, the request has not yet resolved (gotten a response), which is why you wont get any data.

Answer (score 1):

Your fetch countries request in Asynchronous request, so you can't expect countries to be in store just after calling the fetchCountries() function. You will get countries  data when react will re render on arrival of countries data from api.

Answer (score 1):

Your function getCountries return an object with payload = a Promise return by axios, so you don't have your data when you call the function.
To make Async request you should add redux-thunk middleware, after that in your component file create a function

```
const mapStateToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    fetchCountries: bindActionsCreator(fetchCountries, dispatch)
})
```

and pass this function in 2nd argument to your connect function.

In your actions.js change your function getCountries like so:

```
export const fetchCountries = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: FETCH_START})
    axios.get(COUNTRIES_URL)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(data => dispatch({type: FETCH_COUNTRIES, payload: data})
        .catch(errors => dispatch({type: FETCH_ERRORS})
}
```

With that, in your reducer you can set a variable `loading` to true when request start and pass this variable to false when Promise is resolved/rejected and after that you can create a condition to your component to be sure you have your data!